# Call event after document library created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, publishing-site

I have kofax export connector which will create document library in run time. I have create my Document set pro-grammatically. I wanted to add my document set to the document library which is created by kofax export connector. For that i want to know is there any event available while creating the document library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there are four List Event Receivers:

ListAdding(SPListEventProperties)

ListAdded(SPListEventProperties)

ListDeleting(SPListEventProperties)

ListDeleted(SPListEventProperties)

You may be interested in first two. See here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadding(v=office.14).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadded(v=office.14).aspx